# How to use SVG markers in google_maps_flutter Flutter plugin?

Tags: svg, flutter, google-maps-markers

I wish to place markers using .svg images as icons. I am using google_maps_flutter library. This worked with .png converted images but I didn't find a way to use .svg files directly.

I am posting here after reading this issue : [Using SVG markers in google_maps_flutter Flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655554/using-svg-markers-in-google-maps-flutter-flutter-plugin)

And trying to use the method fromAssetImage as described in this thread : [How to change the icon size of Google Map marker in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/change-icon-size-of-google-map-marker-flutter)

I hoped that this new version of the library would help solve my issue.

I tried solving it with the following code :

**MapWidget class**

```dart
for (Place place in widget.places) {
          place.toMarker(
            context,
            () => _onPlaceTapped(place),
          ).then(setState((){
            markerSet.add
          }));
      }
```

**Place class**

```dart
Future<Marker> toMarker(BuildContext context, VoidCallback onTap) async {
    return Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(id.toString()),
      position: LatLng(lat, lon),
      icon: await category.markerIcon(createLocalImageConfiguration(context)),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
```

**Category class**

```dart
Future<BitmapDescriptor> markerIcon(ImageConfiguration configuration) async {
    BitmapDescriptor b;
    switch (type) {
      case CategoryType.FirstCategory:
        b = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, 'assets/markers/marker-first.svg');
        break;
      case CategoryType.SecondCategory:
        b = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, 'assets/markers/marker-second.svg');
        break;
      default:
        b = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, 'assets/markers/marker-third.svg');
        break;
    }

    return b;
  }
```

The images' path is already added to pubspec.yaml if you are wondering.

I expected the default red google markers to be replaced by some custom markers (there should be a small icon image on each custom marker) on the map, however only default markers are shown (not the default in the switch statement, I am speaking of google's default markers).

There is no error message using iOS simulator and google_maps_flutter 0.5.15+1 library version.

Comment: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage() does not work with SVG files. Please check my answer on the question you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609840/2344535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SVG markers in google\_maps\_flutter Flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655554/using-svg-markers-in-google-maps-flutter-flutter-plugin)

Comment: Indeed, we are talking of the same issue. I tried what was recommended on that post, but it didn't work for me. So I thought I could create a post showing the code I tried. In such a case, should I close the issue ? I see there are new answers, so I might find my solution there now.

Comment: Have you tried using flutter_svg? I believe the answer using that package was not yet posted at the time you created your question.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't. I was referring to my situation back then. I'll try your solution as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rednuht ! This worked like a charm. As I can't comment on your answer yet (<50 rep), i'll tell you here to rename `drawableRoot` as `svgDrawableRoot` and maybe to add a comment saying that the dimensions used in `picture.toPicture(32, 32)` must be carefully chosen, otherwise the svg image won't be displayed entirely.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to scale up and down the resulting image ? My markers are too small when I use svg image.

Comment: I've also found scaling to be tricky. DrawableRoot.toPicture() takes a size argument, which you can set in addition to the size parameters in picture.toImage(). Neither seem to take the device's pixel ratio into account. So you need to get the pixel ratio from a MediaQuery and multiply that by the desired size. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question here :

[Using SVG markers in google_maps_flutter Flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655554/using-svg-markers-in-google-maps-flutter-flutter-plugin)

I tried rednuht's answer and it worked like a charm.

**EDIT (recap)**

The answer requires the use of flutter_svg plugin (^0.13 or 0.14.1 seemed to work for myself).

First, create a function that will give you a BitmapDescriptor from the asset. Make sure the asset is declared in your pubspec file.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';


Future<BitmapDescriptor> _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(BuildContext context, String assetName) async {
    String svgString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assetName);
    //Draws string representation of svg to DrawableRoot
    DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgString, null);
    ui.Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture();
    ui.Image image = await picture.toImage(26, 37);
    ByteData bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

I instantiated a Map object at the start of my app so that I could use the BitmapDescriptors without using a lot of async/await calls.

**data_model.dart**

```
Map<CategoryType, BitmapDescriptor> descriptors = Map<Category, BitmapDescriptor>();

Future<void> loadBitmapDescriptors(context) async {
    descriptors[CategoryType.FirstCatgory] = await _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(context, 'assets/markers/marker-first.svg');
    descriptors[CategoryType.SecondCategory] = await _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(context, 'assets/markers/marker-second.svg');
    descriptors[CategoryType.ThirdCategory] = await _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(context, 'assets/markers/marker-third.svg');
  }
```

**main.dart**

```
DataModel.of(context).loadBitmapDescriptors(context);
```

So all I had to do after that was to call it correctly when needed.

```
Marker marker = Marker(markerId: MarkerId(id.toString()), icon: descriptors[category], position: LatLng(lat, lon));
```

Comment: Please brief the content since the link can be outdated

Comment: DataModel is what in this case ? also where in main.dart did you put this line DataModel.of(context).loadBitmapDescriptors(context); Thanks good answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended with this implementation due to without de devicePixelRatio It was showing pixelated markers.

```dart
Future<BitmapDescriptor> getBitmapDescriptorFromSVGAsset(
    BuildContext context,
    String svgAssetLink, {
    Size size = const Size(30, 30),
  }) async {
    String svgString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
      svgAssetLink,
    );
    final drawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(
      svgString,
      'debug: $svgAssetLink',
    );
    final ratio = ui.window.devicePixelRatio.ceil();
    final width = size.width.ceil() * ratio;
    final height = size.height.ceil() * ratio;
    final picture = drawableRoot.toPicture(
      size: Size(
        width.toDouble(),
        height.toDouble(),
      ),
    );
    final image = await picture.toImage(width, height);
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final uInt8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(uInt8List);
  }
```