# Custom map marker icons are pixelated on physical devices

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

On Android and iOS, my custom map markers (PNG files) are pixelated on the google_maps_flutter map on physical devices. They are fine on simulators. Why is this?

Code:

Client usage:

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    createLocalImageConfiguration(
      context,
      size: selected ? const Size(50, 58.2035) : const Size(35, 40.7422),
    ),
    filePath,
  );
} else {
  return getBitmapDescriptorFromAssetBytes(
    filePath,
    selected ? 150 : 100,
  );
}
```

Methods called from above:

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> getBitmapDescriptorFromAssetBytes(
  String path,
  int height,
) async {
  final Uint8List imageData = await getBytesFromAsset(path, height);
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(imageData);
}

Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int height) async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
  ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
    data.buffer.asUint8List(),
    targetHeight: height,
  );
  ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!
      .buffer
      .asUint8List();
}
```

When I use the web code block from the client usage above (`BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage`) on Android and iOS, the map markers are not pixelated, but they are way too big, and do not get smaller when changing the size.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636001/3935156) talks about making it less pixelated by doing:

```
  final ratio = ui.window.devicePixelRatio.ceil();
  final height1 = height.ceil() * ratio;
```

And I did that, but it didn't become less pixelated, perhaps because he used SVG's and I am using PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way, drawing on the canvas with a medium quality filter, but you need both dimensions of the image (width x height).

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> getBitmapDescriptorFromAssetBytes(
  String path,
  double width,
  double height,
) async {
  var imageFile = await rootBundle.load(path);
  var pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  var canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
  var imageUint8List = imageFile.buffer.asUint8List();
  var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imageUint8List);
  var imageFI = await codec.getNextFrame();

  //Set the filter for the image, the default is low.
  paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
      image: imageFI.image,
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium);

  var image = await pictureRecorder
      .endRecording()
      .toImage(width.toInt(), height.toInt());
  var data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data!.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works amazingly well, thanks!