# How to convert SVG to PNG in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I am looking to convert SVG from assets to png and write it to File.

I have managed to write SVG to file, but I want to write the image to a file as a PNG

code that writes SVG to file :

```
 final bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/example.svg');
  final String tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  final File file = File('$tempPath/profile.svg');
  await file.writeAsBytes(
      bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
  return file;
}
```

Comment: any update about this?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to your problem on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63215502/3781411).

You will need to add `flutter_svg` as a dependency of your project.

This is almost a copy past of the code given on the referenced answer:

```
Future<Uint8List> svgToPng(BuildContext context, String svgString,
    {int svgWidth, int svgHeight}) async {
  DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgString, null);

  // to have a nice rendering it is important to have the exact original height and width,
  // the easier way to retrieve it is directly from the svg string
  // but be careful, this is an ugly fix for a flutter_svg problem that works
  // with my images
  String temp = svgString.substring(svgString.indexOf('height="') + 8);
  int originalHeight =
      svgHeight ?? int.parse(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('p')));
  temp = svgString.substring(svgString.indexOf('width="') + 7);
  int originalWidth =
      svgWidth ?? int.parse(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('p')));

  // toPicture() and toImage() don't seem to be pixel ratio aware, so we calculate the actual sizes here
  double devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

  double width = originalHeight *
      devicePixelRatio; // where 32 is your SVG's original width
  double height = originalWidth * devicePixelRatio; // same thing

  // Convert to ui.Picture
  final picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture(size: Size(width, height));

  // Convert to ui.Image. toImage() takes width and height as parameters
  // you need to find the best size to suit your needs and take into account the screen DPI
  final image = await picture.toImage(width.toInt(), height.toInt());
  ByteData bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

  return bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DrawableRoot isnt available in newer Versions of `flutter_svg`. The new way of doing it is by using the VectorGraphicUtilities:

```
final pictureInfo = await vg.loadPicture(SvgStringLoader(...));
final image = await pictureInfo.picture.toImage(...);
```

The result is a Bitmap-Image and can be turned into any other supported Format e.g. png:

```
final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
final pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
```

And can then be saved as a Img on the Device:

```
final file = await File('test.png').create();
await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
```

So everything put together:

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
Future<Uint8List> svgToPng(String svgString, BuildContext context) async {
  final pictureInfo = await vg.loadPicture(SvgStringLoader(svgString), context);

  final image = await pictureInfo.picture.toImage(100, 100);
  final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

  if (byteData == null) {
    throw Exception('Unable to convert SVG to PNG');
  }

  final pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  return pngBytes;

}
```

Comment: The amount of sheer love I have for you right now is unimaginable.
I've been stuck on this for the past 3 days trying to find how to make it work for the newer version.
THANK YOU <3

Answer (score 1):

@pierre-hubert answer is nice. But I had to do some changes to get it working.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

Future<Uint8List> svgToPng(BuildContext context, String svgString,
    {int? svgWidth, int? svgHeight}) async {
  DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgString, "key");
  // Parse the SVG file as XML
  XmlDocument document = XmlDocument.parse(svgString);

  // Getting size of SVG
  final svgElement = document.findElements("svg").first;
  final svgWidth = double.parse(svgElement.getAttribute("width")!);
  final svgHeight = double.parse(svgElement.getAttribute("height")!);
  // toPicture() and toImage() don't seem to be pixel ratio aware, so we calculate the actual sizes here
  double devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

  double width = svgHeight * devicePixelRatio;
  double height = svgWidth * devicePixelRatio;

  // Convert to ui.Picture
  final picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture(size: Size(width, height));

  // Convert to ui.Image. toImage() takes width and height as parameters
  // you need to find the best size to suit your needs and take into account the screen DPI
  final image = await picture.toImage(width.toInt(), height.toInt());
  ByteData? bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

  return bytes!.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

You can then use `Image.memory()` widget to render the result

Answer (score 0):

i am providing here latest solution according to the latest plugin.[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)
To assign the exact width and height to the output image, you need to extract the width and height values from the SVG by parsing it, use [xml plugin.](https://pub.dev/packages/xml).

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

 Future<Uint8List?> svgToPng(String svgString) async {

// first parse svgString to get width and height using xml plugin   
    final document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(svgString);
    final svgElement = document.rootElement;
    final widthAttribute = svgElement.getAttribute('width')!.replaceAll("px", "");
    final heightAttribute = svgElement.getAttribute('height')!.replaceAll("px", "");
 

    final  svgDrawableRoot = await vg.loadPicture(SvgStringLoader(svgString), null);
    // same thing

    // Convert to ui.Image. toImage() takes width and height as parameters
    // you need to find the best size to suit your needs and take into account the screen DPI
    final image = await svgDrawableRoot.picture.toImage(int.parse(widthAttribute.toString()),int.parse( heightAttribute.toString()));
    ByteData? bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

    return bytes?.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```